# GGplot does not recognize the grouping variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, finance

a simple ggplot exercise has turned into a frustrating experience...namely, I want to recreate the chart.Events function from PerformanceAnalytics package with GGplot, i.e. create a chart of cumulative returns after a vector of event dates. It has worked several times in the past, but for some reason the following code does not produce the desired result:

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(TTR)
library(purrr)

getSymbols("AAPL")
Dates <- AAPL %>% timetk::tk_tbl(.) %>% dplyr::mutate(CC_Index = TTR::CCI(HLC(.),  n = 20, maType = "SMA")) %>%
dplyr::arrange(CC_Index) %>% dplyr::slice(n = 1:30) %>%  .$index

  purrr::map(match(Dates, AAPL %>% timetk::tk_tbl(.) %>% .$index), function(x) Willis %>% 
           dplyr::mutate(Returns = c(0, diff(log(Close))), Start = x)   %>%
           dplyr::slice(x:(x+20)) %>% dplyr::mutate(Cum_Returns = cumprod(1+.$Returns), indeks = 1:length(Time))) %>% 
           dplyr::bind_rows(.) %>%
           dplyr::select(indeks, Cum_Returns, Start)   %>% dplyr::group_by(Start) %>% 
           ggplot(.) + geom_line(aes(x = indeks, y = Cum_Returns, colour = Start))
```

What I would like to get of course is the standard "spread out" chart showing cumulative returns for a certain asset after a vector of events. Instead, I get this:

[image]

Somehow it just doesn't recognises Start column as the grouping column. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's `Willis` in your Env.? `object 'Willis' not found`

Comment: Oh, sorry, Willis is AAPL %>% timetk::tk_tbl(.)...was playing around with another data set and forgot to change the code.

Comment: `ggplot` does not undertand the `dplyr` `group_by()` statement. Using `group_by` will never change the appearance of the plot. However, ggplot does have a `aes(group=)` aesthetic. However  I think the problem is that you want to treat Start as a factor rather than numeric value? Maybe try `colour = factor(Start)` in your `aes()`?

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you, `factor(Start)` works perfectly...had a hunch integer class might be a problem, as I usually use colour on a character, which works without the `factor(.)`.

Comment: You can also remove the `dplyr::group_by(Start)` since it's not doing anything here.